# How do I use npm packages in my projects

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, masonry

I have been using nodejs a lot lately but I keep coming up against a similar error. There are a huge amount of projects out there and a lot of them have npm packages, but whenever I attempt `npm install --save some-package` I can't seem to figure out how to use them. I don't mean things like express, or mongoose, which I seem to be able to use just fine. I mean things like Bootstrap, or right now, `masonry-layout`.

For instance I followed the steps on the masonry layout page, and executed the following steps:

`npm install --save masonry-layout`

Then according to the [npm page for masonry-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/masonry-layout) I added to following to my general purpose `scripts.js` files (I am keeping small snippets I need in here until I separate code more logically):

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options... 
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

However I get the following error in my console on page load:

```
TypeError: $(...).masonry is not a function
    $('.grid').masonry({
```

I get similar problems when I try and use other frontend node modules or projects. Am I missing something? I always just end up using the cdn or installing the files manually and I am getting tired of working that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to include those scripts in your page.

Use a good old `<script src="…">` or some module loader. (e.g. [require.js](http://requirejs.org/))

Comment: Do you mean point to some script inside the folder in `node_modules` or from my own script? I am loading my script but nothing pointing to a document in `node_modules` where the module was installed. is require.js separate from the typical require call made in a node `app.js` file?

Comment: @eignhpants You are not inside a node app – you are in a website that is rendered in a browser. And you need to tell that browser where to find all those script files. Yes it should be a link to the module inside `node_modules`if you use those at the client side. (Explaining JS module loader likes require.js is out of scope here; see: http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/ or http://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2012/08/13/javascript-module-loaders-necessary-evil/)

Comment: How does a tool like bower fit into all of this? From what I know it seems like it could be used to perform a similar task.

Comment: @eignhpants Yes, Bower and npm are both package managers – Bower is meant for the client side (i.e. browser) while npm is usually used on a server environment (e.g. in a Node app)

Answer (score 0):

what I did was instead of using masonry package download jQuery masonry script and add it as a "script tag" /js file
and you can form layout easily in css

Answer (score 0):

The `masonry-layout` npm package will install the .js you need into `node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js`. You need to include that file in a `<script>` tag on your page.